# xml buttons in excel tabs stored in personal.xlsb

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add buttons to the user interface to my Personal.xlsb file that I share with my colleges.

I am trying to use http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm(UI editor to add custom xml), but nothing shows up on my hometab, so I am thinking it might have to be that the fileformat is personal.xlsb and xlsm or? But I heard that xlsb loads way faster than xlsm, so I would not like to change the fileformat. Any idea how to make custom menus in excel?

Comment: Your best bet is to create the interface (and any macro's that go along with it) as a separate Excel workbook and save this as an add-in. See: http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/buildexceladdin.asp

Comment: Great! What is the difference between addIn and personal.xlsb and how can I distribute and automatically update the addin? Is it always loaded on startup in same way as personal.xlsb?

Comment: Maybe I should open a new question? There is problem with moving from xlsb to xlam, how can I write a routine that start on opening of xlam, in personal.xlsb that goes in thisworkbook module and also I am having problems with `Dim objRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` in xlam file.. So moving to xlam seem impossible?

Comment: However I could have an addin that just holds the GUI and fires off my macros in personal. xlsb

Comment: That would mean you would have to share your personal.xlsb with others, as they may not have the same macro's in their personal.xlsb. To get the XML part working, check the referencse in your personal.xlsb's VBA project en make sure the right ones are also set in the xlam file. An xlam is just a normal excel file, so it has its own ThisWorkbook module.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is,

1. Save your personal.xlsb to personal.xlam (addin file)
2. add the xml to personal.xlam file using the UI editor
3. copy this edited personal.xlam file to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\`
4. Now open excel. goto Developer tab and select Add-ins. Now your addin file name should be listed there. check that box and click OK.
5. Reopen excel and you should be seeing your button in the ribbon in the tab mentioned in your xml

Now whenever you open excel, the button will be displayed in the ribbon until you uncheck it from the Developer->Add-ins

Note : Now if you open personal.xlsb, it will throw an error as excel loads the same procedure which is in your personal.xlsb from the personal.xlam file as well. so delete the macro procedure from personal.xlsb thereafter

Answer (score 0):

The problem with moving to xlam is that I cant get the code in thisworkbook to fire on launch:

```
Private Sub workBook_open()

    Dim ExcelArgs As String
    ExcelArgs = Environ("ExcelArgs")

    Call deleteMacros.deletePersonalFiles
    'MsgBox ExcelArgs
    If UCase(ExcelArgs) = "CREO" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Call Creo.addNewPartToPartslist
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    If InStr(UCase(ExcelArgs), "DOKLIST") >= 0 Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Call ProsjektListen.dbDumpDocOut(Split(ExcelArgs, ",")(1))
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If


    Set myHelper = New Helper
    Call VersionControl.checkLatestVersion

    Call Menu.toolBar

'    temp = Split(Parameters.CmdLineToStr, "\")
'    MsgBox Len(temp(UBound(temp)))
'    If Len(temp(UBound(temp))) > 15 Then
'        'Call Creo.addNewPartToPartslist
'    End If
'
    On Error Resume Next
    Call filter.Unhide_All_Columns
    Sheets("List").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

as well as this declaration is unvalid :

```
Dim objRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
```

The easiest is probably to keep the personal.xlsb and add addin file that just have the buttons but calls : Personal!runMyMacro when its pressed.